# MySQL workbench import issue "load data infile"

Tags: mysql, import, bigdata

I'm using MySQL Workbench, trying to import the dataset which is 217m size.

You can copy and paste the whole thing into sql and run it.

The dataset can be downloaded [here](https://drive.google.com/file/d/1xNzTUjZjcn9xR_QUZbHMdPQizkHEo063/view?usp=share_link)

No matter what I do, which dataset I changed to, it all comes back with the same error:

> code 1083 Field separator argument is not what is expected;

I have talked to chatgpt the whole time trying to solve this problem but with everything chatgpt told me to do, the issue is still there.

I have defined the dataset encoding mode - Set character set for all components to utf8mb4

I have confirmed my dataset is csv with comma

Code here:

```
SET NAMES utf8mb4;

ALTER DATABASE greenhouse SET utf8mb4;

ALTER TABLE cement_emissions CONVERT TO CHARACTER SET utf8mb4 COLLATE utf8mb4_unicode_ci;

show variables like "local_infile";

set global local_infile=1;

CREATE TABLE cement_emissions (
    asset_id INT,
    iso3_country VARCHAR(3),
    original_inventory_sector VARCHAR(255),
    start_time DATETIME,
    end_time DATETIME,
    temporal_granularity VARCHAR(255),
    gas VARCHAR(255),
    emissions_quantity FLOAT,
    emissions_factor FLOAT,
    emissions_factor_units VARCHAR(255),
    capacity FLOAT,
    capacity_units VARCHAR(255),
    capacity_factor FLOAT,
    created_date DATETIME,
    modified_date DATETIME,
    asset_name VARCHAR(255),
    asset_type VARCHAR(255),
    st_astext VARCHAR(255)
);

LOAD DATA INFILE 'C:\ProgramData\MySQL\MySQL Server 8.0\Uploads\SQL projects\Greenhouse Gas Emissions Dataset more than 80G\manufacturing.asset_cement_emissions.csv'
INTO TABLE cement_emissions
FIELDS TERMINATED BY ','
ENCLOSED BY '""'
ESCAPED BY '\\'
LINES TERMINATED BY '\r\n'
IGNORE 1 ROWS ;
```

I've also tried all the following types:

```
FIELDS TERMINATED BY ';'

FIELDS TERMINATED BY '/t'

FIELDS TERMINATED BY '\r\n'

FIELDS TERMINATED BY '\r'
```

Comment: Can you use code formatting for the parts which are code?

Comment: Please edit the question to limit it to a specific problem with enough detail to identify an adequate answer.

Comment: Your link comes up with a "Request access" dialog. Try `FIELDS TERMINATED BY ',' OPTIONALLY ENCLOSED BY '"'`.

Comment: thank you, i have updated the link and i have tried the 
FIELDS TERMINATED BY ',' OPTIONALLY ENCLOSED BY '"'

Comment: Which version of MySQL?

Comment: Provide 2 lines of source in the Question.  And check to see if those two lines are loaded without problems.  If that works, there may be some line much later in the file that is the problem.